# OpenCL: how to avoid duplicate scalar/vector functions?

Tags: kernel, opencl

OpenCL built-in math functions accept abstract `gentype` as argument types, so you have only one `exp(x)` or `log(x)` function and the compiler switches automatically to the right one depending on the actual arguments type when you call them.

I need to program other math functions that will perform a set of basic algebraic operations like `(log(a / b) - c) / d` (no vertical vector algebra), but sometimes on `float` scalars, sometimes on `float4` vectors. Is there a clean way to only code them once and have the compiler switch the same depending on argument type ?

Alternatively, if I write only the `float` scalar code and loop over a `float4` to apply it, is the compiler able to vectorize it ?

Answer (score 1):

`OpenCL` is based on the C programming language and I think the only way to avoid code duplication for each type would be to use C-style macros.

One of the way to use them would be to have macro for type, for example like this:

```
#define vt(t,s) t##s
#define vector_type(t,s) vt(t,s)

typedef vector_type(float, VECTOR_SIZE) vfloat;
```

And then for example `VECTOR_SIZE=4` could be passed to compiler to use `float4`. But that would work for vector types only. To use whether `float` or `float4` needs slightly different macro.

> Alternatively, if I write only the float scalar code and loop over a
>   float4 to apply it, is the compiler able to vectorize it ?

It may or may not, it depends on many things. Also OpenCL compilers are not as advanced as for example gcc and may not generate vectorized code when you would expect them to do. The only way to know is to try.

Answer (score 0):

Using only a scalar function and unrolling it on each vector element if needed seems to produce no slowdown, compared to the full vector path, on Intel Neo and Nvidia OpenCL, with LLVM 10 and Clang 10 (not sure which compiles what though).

So it would seem that the scalar code is properly vectorized when needed, and I don't need to maintain a specific vectorized path manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "C++ for OpenCL" (which is not OpenCL C++) and use a C++ template in your kernel code. Most of the modern LLVM-based implementations support it, but you'll have to check your specific platform(s).